# The latest version of chrome (16.0.912.77) has changed the way it treats CSS absolute positioning?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position

i have a webpage that used to be displayed correctly at the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Until yesterday. The latest version of Chrome (16.0.912.77) OR my CSS has a feature of not displaying absolute positions found in my CSS file.

Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Thank you

Comment: No. Please send a link to jsfiddle demo that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a problem with this version of Chrome when using absolute positioning and any sort of indexing: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111421

Comment: That is exactly what i am talking about